# Magic Numerical Equations

Tags: riddle, mathematics

What number is `?` in follow?

```
2  = 46
4  = 812
8  = 1624
16 = ?
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> $4+6 = 10 = 2 \cdot 5$,  $8+12 = 20 = 4 \cdot 5$,  $16+24 = 40 = 8 \cdot 5$,  $32+48 = 80 = 16 \cdot 5$

or

> $6-4=2$, $12-8=4$, etc.

Therefore,

> So $? = 3248$

Of course, there are many possible solutions to this question...

Comment: Correct ....! +1

Answer (score 6):

> 3248

I think the right side of the equation are actually always 2 numbers that are respectively the double and triple of the number on the left.

```
2 = 4 6
4 = 8 12
8 = 16 24
16 = 32 48
```

Comment: Correct ...! +1